# What's the difference between named pipe and mailslot (mailbox)?

Tags: winapi, ipc, named-pipes

It seems these 2 IPC mechanisms are very similar with each other, is there any difference between them?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think the introductions to each mechanism on MSDN answers this:

1. [Mailslots](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/aa365576%28VS.85%29.aspx):

   > A mailslot is a mechanism for one-way interprocess communications (IPC). Applications can store messages in a mailslot. The owner of the mailslot can retrieve messages that are stored there. These messages are typically sent over a network to either a specified computer or to all computers in a specified domain.
2. [Named Pipes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/aa365590%28VS.85%29.aspx):

   > A named pipe is a named, one-way or duplex pipe for communication between the pipe server and one or more pipe clients. All instances of a named pipe share the same pipe name, but each instance has its own buffers and handles, and provides a separate conduit for client/server communication

So:

- Named pipes are connection orientated, mailslots are not.
- Mailslots can be used for broadcast, named pipes cannot.

(Summary: mailslots are rather like UDP, but named pipes are closer to TCP. The 424 byte limit of mailslots between computers is even more limited than UDP packets on normal networks.)

While both mailslots and named pipes can have ACLs (limiting what actions different client users can do), named pipes also allow delegation of client's identity so the server can act (access other resources) as that user (or be blocked).

(Edited to correct information on security, and note mailslot message size limit.)

Comment: `Also named pipes provide no security mechanisms, whereas named pipes have` - a typo?

Comment: I was saying that probably you meant to say "*mailslots* provide no security mechanisms", as named pipes are subject to NT security.

Comment: @Eugene: *now I see* :-). The challenges of proof readfing – I read what I think I wrote!

Comment: Mailslots also take `LPSECURITY_ATTRUBUTES`, they are named kernel objects. They do provide security!
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/aa365147(v=VS.85).aspx

Comment: @Ajay: Compare the description of the `lpSecurityAttributes` on `CreateNamedPipe`: for mailslots only the `bInheritHandle` is described, but `CreateNamedPipe` (and other create functions for kernel objects) the description talks about the ACL as well. Ie. that parameter is only used to set handle inheritance.

Comment: Look at this sample: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/CppMailslotServer-43b701b6/sourcecode?fileId=21570&pathId=1980421401

Comment: @Ajay: Based on the doc's, and some searching to find any examples of ACL taking effect: I'm not convinced. However there is a C# port of that [sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/CSMailslotServer-1ca18b47/sourcecode?fileId=21681&pathId=1740897596) which (give >5 years since any significant Win32 native coding) will be much easier to try...

Comment: It is worth to say that 400B message size limit is only a case when message is broadcasted. This is what MSDN says: "Messages broadcast to all mailslots on a domain can be no longer than 400 bytes, whereas messages sent to a single mailslot are limited only by the maximum message size specified by the mailslot server when it created the mailslot."

Answer (score 0):

Mailslots dont have definite ACL based permissions as in named pipe. It is not possible to block specific set of users from accessing mail slot. Source windows security book.